# How do I correct this error while appending to a log file using log4j2?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

Error report says:

```
2016-06-17 09:37:14,122 main ERROR Error processing element Appender ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2016-06-17 09:37:14,168 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "Console" for logger config "root"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
  <Appender type="File" name="Console" fileName="C:\Users\raghi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mdepth\JavaApplication3\build\classes\oo.txt">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Appender>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
    <Root level="info">
      <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

It looks like we can't append this way to the log file. There is something wrong here. Please help me out on this instead of any downvotes.

Comment: Why do you define 3 root loggers? if you need the trace level, just leave this one there and remove info and error, you'll get them anyway. (all of them point to the console)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a mix of the strict syntax and non-strict syntax. You also have 3 root loggers but you can only have one. Please review http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html